# Is there an online example of all the colours in System.Drawing.Color?

Tags: c#, user-interface, system.drawing.color

Can anyone point me to a reference chart that has swatches of all the colours that are represented in System.Drawing.Color?

Comment: I think they're exactly the same --> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors

Comment: @Ran - SO is better than google.

Comment: Colours is how we spell it over here in Blighty.

Comment: What subset of the 1.6 million are you interested in?  Or are you talking about KnownColor?

Comment: @Hans System.Drawing.Color has static properties for the known colours.

Comment: @jball You could try and spell the OP's name correctly :P

Comment: @chibabcity - a typo serves me write four talcking about spelling... Been too long for an edit though - deleting and reposting.

Comment: @Martin, I agree that it's a better way to spell it, but when your question is about the `Color` class I think the difference in spelling is jarring.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

[From here:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.brushes)

> The following image shows the color of each predefined brush, its
>   name, and its hexadecimal value.

May as well have the details right here on SO:

[image]

Answer (score 16):

"Web Colors - X11 color names" from wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names

WPF Colors

> Color names in Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) match the color names in Microsoft .NET Framework, Windows Forms, and Microsoft Internet Explorer. These colors and their names are based on the UNIX X11 color values.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brushes.aspx

Comment: Thanks, don't know why I didn't think of Wikipedia.